# Change media type of SOAPUI response

Tags: automated-testing, soapui, rest

I am sending a request with a custom accept header of `application/content.bundle.v1+zip`

The REST service promptly responds;

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/content.bundle.v1+zip
connection: keep-alive
content-encoding: gzip
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

Because of the unrecognized content-type SOAPUI providing me the zip file as a RAW sting of Data.  Is it possible to change the content-type of the response so that SOAPUI interprets it as a standard `application/zip` which in turn it would treat as an attachment?

Comment: As an alternative is it possible to add additional content-types to SoapUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/tips---tricks.html#6-Changing-response-before-it-gets-validated) tip/trick you can modify the response's header. The example shows modifying the content but you should be able to get the gist.

```
if( request.response == null )
return

// get response content
def content = context.httpResponse.responseContent

// manipulate content
content = content.replaceAll( "555", "444" )

// write it back
context.httpResponse.responseContent = content
```

Comment: This has worked for me, just doing a like for like replacement to a default format.